# Calling my method a specific amount of times

Tags: java, merge

In one of my test cases, it checks the number of times that I call the `mergeSort` method and it passes when greater than or equal three. In my code, I call the that method three times with the same object yet my test case says I called it zero times.

My code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class SortTester {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int[] testArray;
    long startTime, endTime;
    int arraySize = 50000;

    // Random Array
    int[] random = makeRandomArray(arraySize);
    // Make array
    Sorter obj = new Sorter();

    // Record start time
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // Sort array using Merge Sort static method
    obj.mergeSort(random, arraySize);

    // Record end time
    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

    // Print out results
    System.out.println("Random array: " + (endTime - startTime));

    // Almost Sorted Array
    int[] sorted = makeAlmostSortedArray(arraySize);
    // Same steps as above
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    obj.mergeSort(sorted, arraySize);
    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Almost Sorted Array: " + (endTime - startTime));


     // Reverse Array
    int[] reverse = makeReverseArray(arraySize);
    // Same steps as above
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    obj.mergeSort(sorted, arraySize);
    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    System.out.println("Reverse Array: " + (endTime - startTime));

}
```

Comment: Where is the test case?